# rspec-railsでgemのgeocoderをテストしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

railsアプリでrspecを使って、gemのgeocoderで取得した住所と緯度経度をテストしたいと思っています。

```
# Gemfile
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'

# pin.rb
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
```

Pinにはlatitudeとlongitudeがあります。
下がschemeのPinです。

```
create_table "pins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "pin_name"
    t.string "address"
    t.decimal "latitude", precision: 23, scale: 20
    t.decimal "longitude", precision: 23, scale: 20
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"
  end
```

住所(address)を入力すると、緯度経度を取得することができるようにしています。

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Pin, type: :model do
    before do
        @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end

    # valid when the corresponded address is got with latitude and longitude
    it "is valid when the address is got with latlng" do
        user = @user
        new_pin = user.pins.create(
            pin_name: "new_pin",
            address: "兵庫県神戸市中央区加納町１丁目３−１",
            description: "search with latlng",
            user_id: 1
        )
        Pin.geocoded_by :address
        expect(new_pin.latitude).to eq 34.706705
        expect(new_pin.longitude).to eq 135.195490
    end
end
```

Pinには外部キーでuser_idが入っているので、facotrybotでuserのインスタンスを作成しています。
addressに住所を入力し、その住所の緯度と経度（googlemapからコピペ）をeqの後に書いています。

しかし、上記のコードを書いた後に、bundle exec rspecを行うと、

```
Failures:

  1) Pin is valid when the address is got with latlng
     Failure/Error: expect(new_pin.latitude).to eq 34.706705

       expected: 34.706705
            got: 0.347056201e2

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/pin_spec.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.03 seconds (files took 3.96 seconds to load)
26 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/pin_spec.rb:88 # Pin is valid when the address is got with latlng
```

という風になってうまく一致してくれません。
geocoderで住所を取得すると、特殊な形で緯度経度が返ってくるなんていう仕様があるのでしょうか。

---

UPDATE
sakuroさまのご指摘の上で修正した後のコードです。

```
  # valid when appropreate latlng is received with an address
  it "is valid when appropreate latlng is received with an address" do
      user = @first_user
      new_pin = user.pins.create(
          pin_name: "new_pin",
          address: "兵庫県神戸市中央区加納町１丁目３−１",
          description: "search with latlng",
          user_id: 1
      )
      Pin.geocoded_by :address
      lat = new_pin.latitude.to_f
      lng = new_pin.longitude.to_f
      expect(lat).to be_within(0.005).of 34.706705
      expect(lng).to be_within(0.005).of 135.195490
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.347056201e2 の e2 って指数表記ですよね。値としては 34.7056201 ってことになりますね。
精度とか測地系の違いであって、特殊な記法の値ではなさそうです。

あと、Floatの比較は[be_within](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher)マッチャを使いましょう。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
返答が大変遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。

sakuroさまのご指摘通りにテストを実行したところ、うまく改善することができました。
ありがとうございます！